# Eclipse Plugin for Websphere Liberty Profile broken in last update? (16.0.0.4)

Tags: eclipse, websphere-liberty

after upgrading WAS Liberty profile plugin in my Eclipse I can't edit Liberty servers (double clicking in the Server view entry). I get a grey page (Wildfly and JBoss servers open OK).

This occurs with all servers... 16.0.0.3 and new 16.0.0.4.
they work (I can edit server configuration (server.xml) and deploy and run but I can't edit the server configuration in Eclipse)

[image]

[image]

I anyway think the problem is in this exception logged in the .metadata/.log file:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2016-12-19 15:50:33.478
!MESSAGE Unable to create class 'org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityEditor' from bundle '1017'
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/ws/st/common/core/internal/RXAInfo
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:356)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:971)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:640)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:746)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:717)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:711)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:695)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer.showTab(StackRenderer.java:1306)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer$1.handleEvent(LazyStackRenderer.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4781)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:211)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.showElementInWindow(ModelServiceImpl.java:572)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.bringToTop(ModelServiceImpl.java:536)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.delegateBringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:724)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.bringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:396)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.showPart(PartServiceImpl.java:1166)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3252)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$25(WorkbenchPage.java:3167)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$10.run(WorkbenchPage.java:3149)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3144)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3108)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3089)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.ServerUIPlugin.editServer(ServerUIPlugin.java:443)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.ServerUIPlugin.editServer(ServerUIPlugin.java:426)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.view.servers.OpenAction.perform(OpenAction.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.view.servers.AbstractServerAction.run(AbstractServerAction.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.RetargetAction.run(RetargetAction.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonNavigatorManager$2.open(CommonNavigatorManager.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.ui.OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper$InternalListener.open(OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$2.run(StructuredViewer.java:854)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireOpen(StructuredViewer.java:851)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1168)
    at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonViewer.handleOpen(CommonViewer.java:449)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$6.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1275)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireOpenEvent(OpenStrategy.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$2(OpenStrategy.java:272)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4230)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1491)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1514)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1499)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1299)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4072)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3698)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:694)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/ws/st/common/core/internal/RXAInfo
    at com.ibm.ws.st.core.internal.WebSphereServer.getRXAProperties(WebSphereServer.java:1377)
    at com.ibm.ws.st.ui.internal.ServerEditorRemoteServerSection.createSection(ServerEditorRemoteServerSection.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.editor.ServerEditorPart.insertSections(ServerEditorPart.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.editor.OverviewEditorPart.createPartControl(OverviewEditorPart.java:316)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.addPage(MultiPageEditorPart.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.addPage(MultiPageEditorPart.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.internal.editor.ServerEditor.createPages(ServerEditor.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.createPartControl(MultiPageEditorPart.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.createPartControl(CompatibilityPart.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityEditor.createPartControl(CompatibilityEditor.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:341)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:898)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:879)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:345)
    ... 92 more
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be working and I tried it with both a new workspace and an old one from 16.0.0.3 and it was ok.  Can you send more details about your setup:

- Operating system and version
- Eclipse version (Help -> About Eclipse)
- Java version
- To see if something went wrong with the install can you do the following: Help -> About Eclipse then click on the [WDT Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RR0E.png) and cut and paste the information
- Contents of the workspace .log file `<workspace location>/.metadata/.log`

A couple of things you can try that might resolve the problem:

- Restart eclipse with the -clean option
- Regenerate the runtime metadata: `Window -> Preferences -> Server -> Runtime Environment -> SELECT YOUR RUNTIME -> CLICK Edit -> CLICK Advanced options... -> CLICK Refresh`, then wait for the timestamp to be updated

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Erin. I have edited the question adding the information you ask for. I am sure the exception can help locate the problem, even though I can't get any conclusions from it. I have never seen that class and don't find much info about it in Google. Thanks again.

Comment: It does look like something went wrong with the install as it is showing 8.5.5.8 instead of 16.0.0.4.  Can you try a clean install and see if that helps?

Comment: it seems there is a problem with the Liberty Plugin for previous version of eclipse (Luna, the one I was using). I have installed Neon and plugin works OK. For previous version, the plugin is not available in the marketplace, only version for Mars (even older) is visible.